# reading off multiple CSV files

Tags: php, csv

need to pull a ton of info, i.e.

file1:

```
 10948|Book|Type1
```

file2:

```
SHA512||0||10948
```

file3:

```
0|10948|SHA512|c3884fbd7fc122b5273262b7a0398e63
```

I'd like to get it into soething like

```
 c3884fbd7fc122b5273262b7a0398e63|SHA512|Type1|Book
```

I do not have access to an actual database, is there any way to do this? Basically looking for a `$id = $file1[0]; if($file3[1] == $id)` or something unles sthere's more efficient.

Each CSV file is anywhere from 100k-300k lines. I don't care if it takes a while, I can just let it run on EC2 for a while.

Comment: Can you use a file-based database, such as SQLite3?  I have a feeling that having this in a database of some sort will come in handy for you later anyway.

Comment: Do you strictly need to do that in PHP?

Comment: Perl, Python are also available, this is in CLI only (no web). It is going into a database via an import feature that only accepts certain things.. the end result is a DB but need to clean some data up first.  I tried sqlite3, but it seems to only take , as a separator strictly which some lines are packed with.

Comment: is each file consistent in the way it is formatted or are these different formats mixed in individual files?

Comment: They are consistent in the way that each one will have the SESS_ID (such as 10948) always be in $file1[0], always be in $file2[5], always be in $file3[1]. I need it to go throguh each ID in file1 only, and pull extraneous data from the others.

Comment: Not familiar with what's available via CLI in EC2, but if it's POSIX then you get 'join' and 'sort' : http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/join/

Comment: EC2 was kinda unrelated, it's just that CPU/disk IO doesn't matter as long as it gets done. I have a user account (no root) with perl/cpan, python, and php5.3

Comment: I would be very, very leery of throwing away the '10948' field, as I see  you've done in your output example. That thing is the only link back to the original three files.

Comment: are the files in sync regading the IDs, e.g. will the first line in all three files always have the same ID or is that completely random, e.g. line 1 in file 1 has ID 12345, line 1 in file 2 has 23456 and so on?

Comment: Files are never in sync, some are blank lines (like 04494|||), some have extra nmbers that are never used in any other files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array();

$fh = fopen('file1') or die("Unable to open file1");
while(list($id, $val1, $val2) = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '|')) {
   $data[$id]['val1'] = $val1;
   $data[$id]['val2'] = $val2;
}
fclose($fh);

$fh = fopen('file2') or die ("Unable to open file2");
while(list($method, null, null, null, $id) = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '|')) {
   $data[$id]['method'] = $method;
}
fclose($fh);

$fh = fopen('file3') or die("Unable to open file3");
while(list(null, $id, null, $hash) = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '|')) {
   $data[$id]['hash'] = $hash;
}
fclose($fh);
```

Tedious, but should you get an array with the data you want. Outputting it it as another csv is left as an exercise to the reader (hint: see [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv)).

Comment: What is this? syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM.. what character is a nekudotayim D:

Comment: it's hebrew for `::`. I see I forgot a closing bracket on the list() in the first while loop. I'll fix up the answer.

Comment: @jmoon - From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator): "In PHP, the scope resolution operator is also called Paamayim Nekudotayim, which means "twice colon" or "double colon" in Hebrew. The name was introduced in the Israeli-developed Zend Engine 0.5 used in PHP 3. Although it has been confusing to many developers who don't speak Hebrew, it is still being used in PHP 5." or directly from [PHP](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

Comment: @jmoon: Not all software is developed in English speaking countries.

Comment: Okay, almost got this working. Unfortunately there's one issue that I just found. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dm1uqw99

Comment: hmmm. just load up a row from file4 as any of the others, then you'd have to search $data for the key where that hash is stored. Alternatively, you could set up a parallel array in the file3 processing section to map hashes->ids, then refer to it in the file4 section.

Answer (score 1):

All three files appear to have a common field (i.e. in your example, "10948" was common to all three lines). If you're not worried about using a lot of memory, you could load all three files in different array, setting the common field as the array key and using a foreach loop to reassemble all three.

For example:

```
$result = array();

// File 1
$fh = fopen('file1');

while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '|')) !== FALSE )
  $result[$data[0]] = $data;

fclose($fh); 

// File 2
$fh = fopen('file2')

while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '|')) !== FALSE )
  $result[$data[5]] = array_merge($result[$data[3]], $data);

fclose($fh); 

// File 3
$fh = fopen('file3')

while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '|')) !== FALSE )
  $result[$data[1]] = array_merge($result[$data[1]], $data);

fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to perform a merged-sort using basic unix tools: 
a) sort your .CSV files by the columns common between each file,  sort -d" " -K? -K? -K? 
b) Using the unix 'join' command to output records common between pairs of .CSV files. 
The 'join' command only works with 2 files at a time, so you'll have to 'chain' the results for multiple data sources:

```
  # where 'x' is field number from file A, and 'y' is field number from file B
  sort -kx "fileA" 
  sort -ky "fileB"
  join -1x -2y  "fileA" "fileB" > file1

  sort -kx "fileC"
  join -1x -2y "file1" "fileC" > file2

  sort -kx "fileD"
  join -1x -2y "file2" "fileD" > file3
  etc...
```

This is very fast, and allows you to filter your .CSV files as if an impromptu database join occurred.

If you have to write your own merge-sort in php:  (Read Here: [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) )

The easiest implementing to merge-sort of .CSV files is 2-stage:  a) unix sort your files, then B) 'merge' all the sources in parallel, reading in a record from each, looking for the case where your value in your common fields match all the other sources (JOIN in database terminology):
rule 1) Skip the record that is less than (<) ALL the other sources. 
rule 2) When a record's common value is equal to (==) ALL other sources do you have a match.  
rule 3) When a record's common value is equal to (==) is SOME of the other source, you can use 'LEFT-JOIN' logic if desired, otherwise skip that record from all sources.

Pseudo code for a join of multiple files

```
read 1st record from every data source;
while "record exists from all data sources"; do
    for A in each Data-Source ; do
        set cntMissMatch=0
        for B in each Data-Source; do
            if A.field < B.field then
               cntMissMatch+=1
            end if
        end for

        if cntMissMatch == count(Data-Sources) then
            # found record with lowest values, skip it
            read next record in current Data-source; 
            break;  # start over again looking for lowest
        else 
            if cntMissMatch == 0 then
                we have a match, process this record;
                read in next record from ALL data-sources ;
                break; # start over again looking for lowest
            else
                # we have a partial match, you can choose to have
                # 'LEFT-JOIN' logic at this point if you choose, 
                # where records are spit out even if they do NOT 
                # match to ALL data-sources. 
            end if         
        end if
    end for       
done
```

Hope that helps.